# How to test if an attribute exists in a file with Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get this tested, but I'm not sure if the if is right

```
if [ $(lsattr /mnt/backup/*.* | grep i) ] ;
then
    echo "file  $_ has i attribute"; 
else
    echo "file $_ does not have i attribute"
fi
```

This is the lsattr on that directory:

```
----i----------------- /mnt/backup/Backup-Full_02-04-2022.7z

---------------------- /mnt/backup/test.7z
```

Thank you

Comment: This will match if any file in that directory has the attribute, or has an "i" in its name, so definitely not what you want. You need to specify a single filename, and either detect an "i" in exactly the right position, or find a command/option that can test one attribute at a time rather than listing them.

Answer (score 3):

With `grep i` you will also match file names containing `i`. Moreover, `$_` is not set so its value is probably just the empty string. If you really want to use an `if` statement you also need a loop. And `grep` is not needed any more if you use the `bash` conditional expressions:

```sh
$ lsattr /mnt/backup/*.* | while read -r attr name; do
    if [[ "$attr" == "*i*" ]]; then
      echo "file $name has i attribute"
    else
      echo "file $name does not have i attribute"
    fi
  done
file /mnt/backup/Backup-Full_02-04-2022.7z has i attribute
file /mnt/backup/test.7z does not have i attribute
```

If you can use `awk` instead of `grep` you can easily limit the search to the first word:

```
awk '$1 ~ "i"'
```

And you don't need any `bash` `if` or `while` loop any more, all this can be embedded in the `awk` script:

```
$ lsattr /mnt/backup/*.* | awk -vs1=" has " -vs2=" does not have " \
    '{print $2 ($1 ~ "i" ? s1 : s2) "i attribute"}'
file /mnt/backup/Backup-Full_02-04-2022.7z has i attribute
file /mnt/backup/test.7z does not have i attribute
```